# "expression must have a constant value" error while using function pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Am getting the error as specified in the title [ using c language]

There is a struct defined

```
typedef struct {
uint a;
mytype b;
} structName
```

where mytype is defined as

```
typedef void (*mytype) (void);
```

A const array of type structName is defined as:

```
CONST(structName, memclass) arr[] = {
{val1, NULLPTR},
{val2, &somefunc}, // somefunc has type 'mytype'
.
.
.
};
```

I have a function and respective function pointer say :

```
void func(int,int);
void (*ptr)(int, int) = &func;
```

Now I want to add this function pointer to the above array something like this:

```
{val3, (*ptr)(1,2)},
```

But I am getting error :
expression must have a constant value

What changes to make in the ptr to make this work?

Comment: In this context, "constant expression" means a compile time constant. This is required for global variables as they are initialized before `main` is called and a proper execution environment is available. Therefore you cannot call a function and use its return value as initializer value for a variable.

Comment: Did you try to use `func` instead of `ptr`? -- Anyway, C does not know "closures", and so you cannot provide actual arguments like this. Additionally, the types of the function pointers are different.

Comment: Besides that, your struct declaration expects to get a function pointer as second value. Your function does not even return a value that could be used here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you cannot use a function call in an initializer list.

Also the return type of your called function does not match the type of the second struct member.

Instead of calling the function you must provide a function pointer.

Normally that would look like this:

```c
{val3, func},
```

In your specific case this will not work properly.
The second member of your struct has type `void(*)(void)` while your function is `void()(int, int)`.
Whenever you use that pointer from the struct, no one will provide the  extra arguments. In case your function uses these parameters, you will invoke undefined behaviour.

If you want to have your function called with parameters `1,2` you might create a wrapper function for that purpose:

```c
void func_wrapper(void)
{
   func(1,2);
}

...
{val3, func_wrapper}
```